# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=2^{n+1}} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^mn}{m}$ converges and evaluate it.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

Noting that the series inside is a part of the alternating harmonic series multiplied by $-n$, we get $\displaystyle \sum_{m=2^{n+1}} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^mn}{m}=\sum_{m=1} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^mn}{m} -\sum_{m=1}^{2^{n+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^mn}{m}=\sum_{m=1}^{2^{n+1}-1}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}n}{m}-n\log2$, hence the initial sum is equivalent to$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1} ^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}n}{m}-n\log2.                                                            \ $$ It is obvious that the $n$-th term tends to $ 0$, so the sum can converge, and in fact I'm quite sure it does, having computed some partial sums as well. Finally, using the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) $ \Phi$, we can rewrite it as $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \Phi(-1,1,2^{n+1}),$$ though this is perhaps  nicer than useful.

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$
\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1} = \frac{1}{4k^2+2k}
$$
write $M=m/2$ to get
$$
T(n) = \sum_{m=2^{n+1}}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m} = \sum_{M=2^n}^\infty \frac{1}{4M^2+2M}
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\int_{t=2^n}^\infty (2t+1)^{-2}~dt < \sum_{M=2^n}^\infty \frac{1}{(2M+1)^2} < T(n) < \sum_{M=2^n}^\infty \frac{1}{4M^2}
< \int_{t=2^n-1}^\infty (2t)^{-2}~dt
$$
and we get the bounds
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n+2}+2} < T(n) < \frac{1}{2^{n+2}-4}
$$
It is thus clear that
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=2^{n+1}} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^mn}{m} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nT(n)
$$
converges. Furthermore, we can use
$$
T(n) = \sum_{M=2^n}^{2^N-1} \frac{1}{4M^2+2M} + T(N)
$$
with the bounds to get an error of order $O(2^{-N})$ and a numerical approximation $S\approx 0.527273$.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Is it possible to prove the (ir)rationality of $ S $?

Comment: Not necessarily asking you to do it, since it looks at least very hard, I'd like some advice on how doing it if it is possible.